# Include instantly calling function

Tags: php, include

I am a student taking a php course and I have been assigned to create a function that creates a square based on a given set of parameters and prints it, but I must use an include statement to print all of the squares.

My Function looks like this :

```
function squareFunction ($size, $r, $g, $b, $backR, $backG, $backB, $posX, $posY, $length, $height) {

//create an empty image background
$imgur = imagecreatetruecolor($size, $size) or die('Cannot initialize new GD image stream');

//define the foreground and background colour
$fgcolour = imagecolorallocate($imgur, $r, $g, $b);
$bgcolour = imagecolorallocate($imgur, $backR, $backG, $backB);

//fill the image with the background colour
imagefill($imgur, 0, 0, $bgcolour);

//draw the rectangle using coordinates defined by the functions paramters
imagefilledrectangle($imgur, $posX, $posY, ($posX + $length), ($posY - $height), $fgcolour);

//output the header to tell browser this is a png
header ('Content-type: image/png');

//Write the image to be a png out
imagepng($imgur);
imagedestroy($imgur);
}
```

and is inside of a file called square.php

However when I try to use include "square.php"; in a seperate php file for example:

```
<?php 

include '../../../square.php';

echo squareFunction(400,0,0,0,100,100,100,0,50,50,50);

?>
```

I just get a broken image link.

I then tried to include a function call at the top of my square.php file, but then when I used the include statement it would just print the square as soon as the include was read and did no other statements in my file.

Sorry for the lengthy post but I have been researching this all week and could not find any information on why this was happening, thank you all in advance.

Comment: did you try it without the echo ?

Comment: Yes I have tried it without the echo, same results

Comment: Does your GD have the ability to generate png files? You can tell from the `phpinfo()` page.

Comment: PNG confirmed as a format, quite a cool function there too, thank you Jack

Comment: Have you tried calling `squareFunction(400,0,0,0,100,100,100,0,50,50,50);` within the `square.php` file the function is in? If that works we know the problem is with the include and not the function itself.

Comment: Yes I have tried that, it worked fine, I also tried leaving the function call in the square.php file and then using include. When I did that it would just print the image when it read the include and performed none of the other operations in the file that the square.php file was included in.